# Tokenizing a string in C using strtok()

Tags: c, string, token, strtok

I'm trying to write a function that takes an HTTP request and extracts a small amount of the data. My function looks like this:

```
char* handle_request(char * req) {
    char * ftoken; // this will be a token that we pull out of the 'path' variable 
    // for example, in req (below), this will be "f=fib"
    char * atoken; // A token representing the argument to the function, i.e., "n=10"     
        ...

    // Need to set the 'ftoken' variable to the first arg of the path variable.
    // Use the strtok function to do this
    ftoken = strtok(req, "&");
    printf("ftoken = %s", ftoken);

    // TODO: set atoken to the n= argument;
    atoken = strtok(NULL, "");
    printf("atoken = %s", atoken);
   }
```

`req` will usually look something like this: `GET /?f=fib&n=10 HTTP/1.1`

Currently, after calling `strtok()`, `ftoken` prints out as `GET /?f=fibGET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1` which is obviously wrong. Ideally, it would be `f=fib` and `atoken` would be `n=10` Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Comment: What should the output look like

Comment: I would avoid `strtok` here and instead roll my own function.

Comment: `strtok` is amazing. I use this almost everyday. Another good function for string parsing is `sscanf`.

Comment: Using `strtok()` is problematic. Any function that uses `strtok()` cannot call onto a library function of any sort that also uses `strtok()`, and any function that uses `strtok()` must not be called by a function that is also using `strtok()`. Plus it zaps the delimiter without telling you what it was. So, using `strtok()` in a function makes that function a pariah w.r.t to any other function using `strtok()`, and its use must be documented so that everyone avoids collisions. The alternatives `strtok_r()` (POSIX) and `strtok_s()` (Microsoft, TR24731-1, ISO/IEC 9899:2011 Annex K) are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input -> `GET /?f=fib&n=10 HTTP/1.1`

Output -> ftoken `f=fib` and atoken `10`

Code ->

```
ftoken = strtok(req, "?"); // This tokenizes the string till ?
ftoken = strtok(NULL, "&"); // This tokenizes the string till & 
                            // and stores the results in ftoken
printf("ftoken = %s", ftoken); // Result should be -> 'f=fib'

atoken = strtok(NULL, "="); // This tokenizes the string till =.
atoken = strtok(NULL, " "); // This tokenizes the string till next space.
printf("atoken = %s", atoken); // Result should be -> 'n=10'
```

Comment: Looks like it works, thank you! One last question. Once I have `atoken` = `n=10`, is there a way to advance the token to remove the "n=" part? Or would I just have to modify the strtok() call? If so, what would I change it to?

Comment: Thanks again. Just curious, would c allow `atoken = strtok(atoken, "=");`? I'm pretty new to the language and not sure if you can call a function with the same variable like that.

Comment: The first variable that you pass to strtok is a string that you want to tokenize. So, you can't pass in atoken in this case.

Comment: C would allow `atoken = strtok(atoken, "=");` and it even has defined behaviour.  In the circumstances, I think you are safe.  I wouldn't normally do it, but...  (And I see that there is disagreement between those responding.)

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample string (req): "GET /?f=fib&n=10 HTTP/1.1", and your wish to extract "f=fib" and "n=10", try this...

```
char *sepChars = " /?&";
char *discard = strtok( req, sepChars );
char *ftoken = strtok( NULL, sepChars );
char *atoken = strtok( NULL, sepChars );
```